# How can I filter matching processes based on execution time?

Tags: linux, awk, grep, centos, ps

How can I print processes that have been executing over 30 minutes?

I can list all processes like so:

```
ps ax pid,etime,ocmd
```

But how can I filter only scripts matching `/var/www/vhosts/path/to/my_script.php` **and** have been executing for over 30 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -eao etime,pid,command | awk -F":" '$2>30' | grep my_script.php
```

**EDIT**

Musth check also hours!! sorry

```
ps -eao etime,pid,command | awk -F":" '$1>=0 || $2>30' | grep my_script.php
```

Comment: I cannot get this to work. I suspect it's because `etime`s less than 1 hour are presented as `00:00`, not `00:00:00`. So a new script that's been running for 1 minute may show `etime` of `01:00`, or another may be running for 45 seconds: `00:45`. Both of these match your `awk -F":" '$1>=0 || $2>30'`.

Comment: I also tried using `NF`, but `awk` fails if the hour doesn't exist: `awk -F":" '$(NF-2)>=0 || $(NF-1)>30'`. What do you recommend?

Comment: I think you should use split, for example, and refer to the number of splitted parts:
`ps -eao etime,pid,command | awk '{  split($1,arra,":"); if(length(arra)>2 && ( arra[1] > 0 || arra[2] > 30 ) ) {print $0 } else if(arra[1]>30){print $0 } }'`

Comment: This way you´ll control the values of all the different parts of the $1 field, and  you´ll be able to check if they are 3 or 2. Then just check hours in arra[] wich is the array informed by split with the separeated values.